# The output of PI controller using opamp is not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pid-controller, closed-loop, error-amplifier

I am designing a closed loop system for dc-dc converter for that I am using error amplifier  and pi controller. For error amplifier and PI controller I am using OP177A opamp. The error amplifier output is coming exactly as per requirement and gain setting. But the PI controller output is not changing properly based on the error amplifier input. That is the output of PI controller showing  fixed value. I want the PI output to change with the error amplifier output.[image: THIS GRAPH SHOW THE PI CONTROLLER OUTPUT][image: THIS GRAPH SHOWS THE ERROR AMPLIFIER OUTPUT].

Comment: As well as the lack of feedback, you need bipolar supplies (eg. +/-15V). The OP177 can only output or handle inputs that are more than a couple volts from the power supply rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your simulation implements no feedback. Therefore, your regulator (more precisely, the *Integral* component) saturates.

You can observe the trend to saturation if you "skip initial operation point solution" in the `.tran` command (or append `uic` to it).